# How to change array for insert array data to database in PHP?

Tags: arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

My framework is Laravel 5.3, How to create array in HTML and insert array to Database in PHP?

For Example `$passenger` is 2.

In HTML:

```
@for($i = 1; $i <= $passenger; $i++)
<li id="passenger-adult-{{ $i }}">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Passenger</legend>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name[]" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Family</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="family[]" required/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
    </fieldset>
</li>
@endfor
```

After send passenger data Array is:

```
Array
(
  [_method] => PATCH
  [_token] => OwNvaXUvoGAKL25UN85GBiV7pN5I2ILEXw7vZrMa
  [name] => Array
    (
        [0] => amir
        [1] => ali
    )

  [family] => Array
    (
        [0] => hesari
        [1] => ahmadi
    )
  .
  .
  .
)
```

But! I need create array in this case, for insert to database:

```
Array
(
  [_method] => PATCH
  [_token] => OwNvaXUvoGAKL25UN85GBiV7pN5I2ILEXw7vZrMa
  [passenger] => Array
    (
        [name] => amir
        [family] => hesari
        .
        .
        .
    )

  [passenger] => Array
    (
        [name] => ali
        [family] => ahmadi
        .
        .
        .
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this code

```
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name[]" required/>
```

to

```
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="passenger[{{$i}}][name]" required/>
```

change this

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="family[]" required/>
```

to

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="passenger[{{$i}}][family]" required/>
```